# Bean not getting injected into arraylist

Tags: java, spring, javabeans

I have tried this:

```xml
<util:list id="list1">
    <value>foo@bar.com</value>
    <value>foo1@bar.com</value>
</util:list>

<util:list id="list2">
    <value>foo2@bar.com</value>
    <value>foo3@bar.com</value>
</util:list>

<util:map id="emailMap" value-type="java.util.List">
    <!-- Map between String key and List -->
    <entry key="entry1" value-ref="list1" />
    <entry key="entry2" value-ref="list2" />
    ...
</util:map>
```

calling this map like this

```xml
<bean id="myBean" class="com.sample.beans">
    <property name="mapArray" ref="emailMap" />
</bean>
```

I have written a test case to see if this being populated, but where this is being called i have added a `Map.isEmpty()` and it always returns true, meaning map is not getting populated. Could you please guide me?

```
   public class beans()
    {
    Map<String, List<String>> mapArray=  new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();

        public void setMapArray(Map<String, List<String>> map)
        {
            this.mapArray= map;
        }

        public Array<String, List<String>> getMapArray()
        {
            return mapArray;
        }

    public void makeObject(String key)
            throws Exception {

        System.out.println(mapArray.isEmpty());

    }

    }
```

The test case calls a function makeobject. Here the value returned is true always
 TEST:

```
public class testing{

@Test(enabled=true)
public void call1() throws {

ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("call.the.xml");
BeanFactory factory = context;
KeyedPoolFactory test = (KeyedPoolFactory) factor.getBean("myBean");

// CALLED MakeObject here. So the make object is being called for sure since it returning true for isEmpty();

}
```

Comment: Post testcode, and the code of the bean that is using this.

Comment: @M.Denium added, please check

Comment: For starters you should be programming to interfaces (that is `Map` and not `HashMap` and `List` instead of `ArrayList`). And how are you testing (please post that code also).

Comment: posted! Please check it out! I am new to both java and spring!

Comment: Please post the actual code. I can make head nor tails from this, 3 different snippets, referencing different classes, files etc. In short if you use the bean from the context it is injected, if you are constructing a new instance yoyurself, that will be empty.

Comment: also your spring xml injects the map to a property emailMap, but your beans class has a mapArray property.